# Which cache is used when using an instruction such as mov (%rip), %eax?

Tags: caching, assembly, x86

I looked at the x86/i64 documentation and could not find the place where they mention that (%rip) uses the instruction cache. Therefore, I'm not 100% sure that this is the case.

I'm wondering whether I'm right. If so, what I'd like to do is use RIP to access a 4KB buffer because the code accessing it is really small (well, small enough to accommodate an extra 4000 bytes.) I know how to do that with g++, but I have not seen a way to do it with cl. That's the other thing I would really appreciate to learn!

With g++ I could write something like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (".align 4                       \n\r"
                      ".big_num:                      \n\r"
                      ".long 0x01020304               \n\r"
                      ".long 0x05060708               \n\r"
                      ".long 0x01020304               \n\r"
                      ".long 0x05060708               \n\r"
                      "movdqa .big_num(%rip), xmm0    \n\r");
```

What would be the equivalent in a Microsoft program?

```
__asm {
  mov big_number(%rip), xmm7
  jmp loop
big_number:
  ???
loop:
}
```

----- Update (Jan 24, 2013)

Actually, the RIP addressing mode is limited to just an offset:

```
mov offset(%rip), reg
```

So it wouldn't help me because I'd need an index as in:

```
mov offset(%rip, %eax, 4), reg
```

which is not possible anyway.

Comment: closest you'll probably get is `_emit`, but IMO, this just seems "wrong", I'd recommend using the techniques described in chapter 7 of Intel's optimization guide: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf

Comment: At first glance I would say that's a load from memory, it will go through the data cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand what the Intel's manual says and depicts, the instruction cache is used for instructions themselves (when they are fetched from farther caches (L2 and L3) and ultimately from the main memory) and the data encoded inside of the instructions.

The instruction cache may suck in some of the data embedded in the code because cache lines have granularity of 32/64 bytes. But that's likely going to be useless because the data that your mov instruction is accessing is going to come via different route, from the data cache.

To sum up:

- L1 cache contains two independent parts: L1 instruction cache and L1 data cache.
- L2 cache is a unified cache for both code and data.
- L3 is also unified as L2.

You might be able to induce a somewhat longer lifetime for a few numbers of the table in L2 if both L1 IC and L1 DC pull stuff from the same place in L2, but that's about it. You will not be able to actually move data into the L1 instruction cache.